# Cannot fetch data from room database to Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-spinner, android-room

This app is to fetch data from api.github.com/users and reflect on spinner

I am getting data in logs on `Splash.java` but unable to reflect data on `Home.java`

MyAppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Users.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class MyAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract MyDao myDao();
    }
```

MyDao.java

```
@Dao
    public interface MyDao {

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        void addUsers(Users users);

        @Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
        List<Users> getUsers();

        @Query("SELECT node_id FROM Users")
        List<String> getNodeId();

    }
```

`getData()` on Splash.java

```
   public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyAppDatabase myAppDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myAppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyAppDatabase.class, "MyDao").allowMainThreadQueries().build();


                //get data from webservice and store locally

                getData();
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    private void getData() {
        //Creating a string request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                Log.e("response", response.toString());
                response.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Users users = new Users();

                        //Set fields in Users object.

                        users.setLogin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Login));
                        users.setId(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Id));
                        users.setNode_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Node));
                        users.setAvatar_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Avatar));
                        users.setGravatar_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gravatar_id));
                        users.setUrl(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_url));
                        users.setHtml_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_htmi_url));
                        users.setFollowers_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Followers_url));
                        users.setFollowing_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Following_url));
                        users.setGists_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gists_url));
                        users.setStarred_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Starred_url));
                        users.setSubscriptions_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Subscriptions_url));
                        users.setOrganizations_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Organizations_url));
                        users.setRepos_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Repos_url));
                        users.setReceived_events_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Received_events_url));
                        users.setType(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Type));
                        users.setSite_admin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Site_admin));
                        users.setEvents_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_events_url));

                        myAppDatabase.myDao().addUsers(users);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                // intent.putExtra("remember", "true");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

`putData()` on `Home.java`

```
  public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyAppDatabase myAppDatabase;

    //To add into spinner
    private ArrayList<String> userType;

    //List of users from Db
    List<Users> users;

    private  Spinner spinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        userType = new ArrayList<>();

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_user_type);

        myAppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyAppDatabase.class,"UsersDb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        //get data from Db and put into arrayList for spinner

        putData();
    }

    private void putData() {

        users =myAppDatabase.myDao().getUsers();
        userType.add("Select UserType"); //Dummy addition

        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
            userType.add(users.get(i).getType());
            Log.e("DistNames",users.get(i).getType());
        }

        users.size();
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Home.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, userType));
    }
}
```

Comment: This _Users users = new Users();_ will only add one item in database. You should change method  _void addUsers(Users users);_ to _void addUsers(List<Users> users)_ which will give you all users from json array response. Also you have to create custom adapter class since you are using custom model class to display data in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are starting activity in the loop itself, which should be actually outside the loop.

Actually, the mistake that you are doing is it will launch Home activity in the first iteration itself and so you are not getting all the data from the API response. To solve this, let the loop iterates through each entry and add into the database, and start the activity when it completes and so outside the loop.

**Wrong:**

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                Log.e("response", response.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Users users = new Users();

                        //Set fields in Users object.

                        users.setLogin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Login));
                        users.setId(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Id));
                        users.setNode_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Node));
                        users.setAvatar_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Avatar));
                        users.setGravatar_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gravatar_id));
                        users.setUrl(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_url));
                        users.setHtml_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_htmi_url));
                        users.setFollowers_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Followers_url));
                        users.setFollowing_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Following_url));
                        users.setGists_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gists_url));
                        users.setStarred_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Starred_url));
                        users.setSubscriptions_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Subscriptions_url));
                        users.setOrganizations_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Organizations_url));
                        users.setRepos_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Repos_url));
                        users.setReceived_events_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Received_events_url));
                        users.setType(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Type));
                        users.setSite_admin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Site_admin));
                        users.setEvents_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_events_url));

                        myAppDatabase.myDao().addUsers(users);

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
//                        intent.putExtra("remember", "true");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            }
        });
```

**Correct:**

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                Log.e("response", response.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Users users = new Users();

                        //Set fields in Users object.

                        users.setLogin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Login));
                        users.setId(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Id));
                        users.setNode_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Node));
                        users.setAvatar_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Avatar));
                        users.setGravatar_id(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gravatar_id));
                        users.setUrl(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_url));
                        users.setHtml_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_htmi_url));
                        users.setFollowers_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Followers_url));
                        users.setFollowing_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Following_url));
                        users.setGists_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Gists_url));
                        users.setStarred_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Starred_url));
                        users.setSubscriptions_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Subscriptions_url));
                        users.setOrganizations_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Organizations_url));
                        users.setRepos_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Repos_url));
                        users.setReceived_events_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Received_events_url));
                        users.setType(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Type));
                        users.setSite_admin(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_Site_admin));
                        users.setEvents_url(jsonObject.getString(Config.TAG_events_url));

                        myAppDatabase.myDao().addUsers(users);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                // intent.putExtra("remember", "true");
                startActivity(intent);

            }               
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: unable to put Intent there .. giving error invalid method declaration

Comment: @RajSharma ohh yeah I wrote it at wrong place, check the updated answer now.

Comment: same no result on spinner

Comment: @RajSharma Let's put the debug point on Home file and check what users.size() value it's having

Comment: Done that .. after for loop .. result is size = 1

Comment: And what is the response length? response.length() , print it or debug it by putting breakpoint

Comment: Giving entire data from github..


{"login":"mojombo","id":1,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjE=","avatar_url":"https:\/\/avatars0.githubusercontent.com\/u\/1?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/mojomb........

Comment: @RajSharma I neither have the code nor have the information what you are trying to achieve, However I am trying to help you in debugging and resolving the issue. I would say you need to put breakpoint and debug each steps to confirm you are passing exact set of data what you are receiving from api.

Comment: Updated the que with entire code on both activity .. please have a look 

all i have to do is to fetch data from github and reflect on Spinner